# Accessing a field value in FinalForm, useField vs useFormState

Tags: react-final-form

I need to access a field value to trigger special logic when it changes.

I can do:

```js
const { input: { value: myField }} = useField("myField");

// do some stuff with myField
```

```js
const state = useFormState();
const myField = state.values.myField;

// do some stuff with myField
```

What is the preferable way ? They are not exactly equivalent, for instance, when myField is not defined, useField will return `''` while useFormState will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the value of one (or maybe up to 3) field(s), use `useField`.

Yes, `useField()` gives you `''`. This is to ensure that the input is controlled.